# Is there a way to submit a form from an online app without using selenium or browser client?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, selenium, web-scraping

I want to build myself an online app that manages inventory for myself and submit the item to a local classified site. This local classified site does not have an API, only some old looking HTML forms which have multiple steps.

Without using selenium / webdriver, or spinning up a virtual client through firefox / chrome, is where a way to remotely submit forms on a webpage? It would have to support some sort of session since the submission process is multiple steps.

I have done it using webdriver and python, and this seems to be the most popular answer to similar questions online.

Comment: You can use `cURL` from PHP.

Comment: Or a similar library in Python.

Comment: Thanks, I am very familiar with PHP, but this is equally as much a learning project. I was thinking of continuing with Python because the requests library looks pretty dead simple. It is my current goal to learn NodeJS. Does NodeJS have a good library anyone can recommend that is similar to requests for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should be able to use any HTTP client / library for this task (as, behind the scenes, everything boils down to just making the correct HTTP calls to some server anyways).

How hard it's going to be greatly depends on how (badly) the application you're interfacing with is designed.

In the simples scenario, you'll want to:

- Login, and keep track of the session cookies
- Send your data via POST to the server

The example here uses Python `requests`, which is pretty much the best option nowadays.

Let's get started.

First, you'll need to inspect your login page form. Usually a look at the page HTML will give you enough information on how to build the request.

An example could be:

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    ...
</form>
```

To keep track of the cookies, we're going to use a `Session` object:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
```

Next, we're going to submit the credentials via POST (assuming your app is at `http://example.com`):

```
response = session.post(
    'http://example.com/login',
    data={'username': 'your_user', 'password': 'your_password'})
```

At this point, you can check `response.ok` to make sure everything went fine. If you inspect `session.cookies` you should see your session cookie being set.

From now on, all requests made to your app using that session will be authenticated, and so equivalent to the ones you run from the browser.

To submit form data, simply start inspecting how the application works (get submit URIs and form field names by inspecting forms, as we did for the login page, and submit the data via POST using the same session).

In case the page HTML is complicated, it might also be helpful to watch the HTTP requests being made by using you browser developers tools, and replicate them via code.

Comment: Thank you redShadow! This is amazing, exactly what I was looking for. I have just one or two small questions.

1. How difficult is it to maintain code that rely's on someone else's website to work? If they change the element name, or make any small change along the way I believe I will need to update my app every time.

2. Do you have a library you might be able to recommend for NodeJS, or would you recommend I stick with Python and maybe Django?

Comment: About maintainability, that's exactly the reason why they invented APIs :) In general, you'd want to have a clear "contract" on how the systems are supposed to integrate, and have some guarantee that things aren't going to suddenly change and break your app. So the best long-term solution would be to convince the author of the 3rd party app to create a proper API you can consume. Unfortunately that's not  always possible, so you need to be careful, and make sure you get notified when things break.

Comment: About Python vs javascript/Nodejs, my personal recommendation is for Python (I have experience building things with both of them, and very much prefer Python under almost all aspects). If you're just getting started with web app development, definitely have a look at django, which provides almost everything you're likely going to need.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the post variables that the post is looking for, you can use [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) in Python2.7, [urllib.requests](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urllib2) in python 3.5 or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to submit each page and get the results, assuming that they truly are just submitting posts.